# data.stackexchange.com query for number of visitors in a time frame?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, statistics

Is there a query available in data.stackexchange.com to access the number of visitors of Photo SE in a given time period?
For example, to get the number of visitor of the site in a particular day?

Answer (score 1):

Visit information is not part of the data made available. The closest possible would be to identify activity on a day, but that won't cover "read-only" visits.

Comment: How about the _Last seen_ info? Number of PhotoSE members having been seen during the last day/week/month? Can that be queried?